# Get SharedPreferences and get the text inside an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am working on an app where I need to refer to an intent, where the intent gets its referingpoint from SharedPreference. My code is like this:

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This is to load the SharedPreferences

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("Import MEM1 here");
   startActivity( intent );
```

I need to know how to import the MEM1, and then refer to it as an intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, you have to clarify in which string preference the name of the package is stored, then get that name then launch the intent.

```
String packageName = sharedPreferences.getString(PACKAGE_NAME_PREF);
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
```

That is, if I understand your question correctly.